# CSS Positioning: Content that should be below the fold is appearing above the fold

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to build a page that is divided into above-the-fold and below-the-fold sections to give the viewer an impression of going undersea.  I've run into a stumbling block, because something just refuses to click in my brain when it comes to the concepts of CSS positioning.

Ultimately, I am trying to add another section below the fold where I can add content, but want the above water scene to stay full width.  Currently, the content I want to appear below the fold is rendering in the above the fold section.

```css
body {
  background: #90caf9;
}

.above-water {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 50% 0%, transparent 30%, #2179ea 30%, #2179ea 45%, #1d86ea 45%, #1d86ea 60%, #2a9eea 60%, #2a9eea 75%, #02b0ea 75%);
  -webkit-animation: anim-h-wave 4s linear infinite, anim-v-wave 2s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: anim-h-wave 4s linear infinite, anim-v-wave 2s infinite alternate;
  animation: anim-h-wave 4s linear infinite, anim-v-wave 2s infinite alternate;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-h-wave {
  0% {
    background-position: -100px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100px 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-h-wave {
  0% {
    background-position: -100px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100px 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-v-wave {
  0% {
    background-size: 100px 220px;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100px 270px;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-v-wave {
  0% {
    background-size: 100px 220px;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100px 270px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="above-the-water">
  <div class="above-water">
    <div class="wave"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="underwater">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

If needed, the full code can be found on my pen at https://codepen.io/sabey-dc/pen/zYOdNOv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to add margin-top: 100vh to the underwater section because since the above water has absolute positioning, it won't push the underwater content down on its own.

Comment: and I would use `width: 100%;` instead of `100vw`, otherwise you'll get also a X-scroll

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I couldn't quite figure out the relationship between the elements.  Thank you!